# Some bootstrap divs are overlapping with other bootstrap div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have created the following layout with bootstrap:
[demo](http://www.bootply.com/ATPMY3SEE4)

As you can see the 'If you would like to know more about...' div is overlapped by the four small divs. Can you give me any suggestions to fix this? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Each new row should wrap around .row div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code..

```
.more-info > div > div:nth-child(3) {
    color: #8b8b8b;
    font-family: calibrilight;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0 139px;
    letter-spacing: -0.3px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    margin-bottom: -42px;
}
```

You have added "margin-bottom:-42px". Remove and check again. if you want to have that part. just include "padding-bottom: 42px". so the space remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use the class row when you want a new line

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
    If you would like to know more about rules and regulations around fgas testing then please click the more info page or read the posts below.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">` after `row` class directly

you don't need `col-lg` becuase it is equal to `col-md` you can only use `col-md`

Modify code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row more-info">

      <div class="col-md-12">
          <img src="img/info-icon.png">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12>">
          MORE INFO
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12">
          If you would like to know more about rules and regulations around fgas testing then please click the more info page or read the posts below.
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 info-box">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              What do the Regulations seek to achieve?
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              Fluorinated gases have a high global warming effect if released into the atmosphere. The principal objective of the EC Regulation is to contain, prevent and thereby...
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
              <a href="#">READ MORE</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 info-box">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              Why is a mandatory certification scheme required?
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              Fluorinated gases have a high global warming effect if released into the atmosphere. The principal objective of the EC Regulation is to contain, prevent and thereby...
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a href="#">READ MORE</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 info-box">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              When do I need to apply?
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              Fluorinated gases have a high global warming effect if released into the atmosphere. The principal objective of the EC Regulation is to contain, prevent and thereby...
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a href="#">READ MORE</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 info-box">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                How will it affect my business?
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                Fluorinated gases have a high global warming effect if released into the atmosphere. The principal objective of the EC Regulation is to contain, prevent and thereby...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a href="#">READ MORE</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12">
          <a href="#">More info page</a>
      </div>

</div>
</div>
```